# How to modify default components in A-frame?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, aframe

Rotation, position, are the components which are attached by default to A-frame entity. I want to modify these components and apply the changes to the entities.

For example if I want to create a new component say "positionnew" with a change in default position. The change from the usual position component is addition of **default: {x: 0, y: -2, z: -2}**

```
 AFRAME.registerComponent('positionnew', {
  schema: { type: 'vec3', default: {x: 0, y: -2, z: -2} },

  update: function () {
    var object3D = this.el.object3D;
    var data = this.data;
    object3D.position.set(data.x, data.y, data.z);
  }
});
```

However, I am not able to see any changes. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a way.
this is the code. update needed to be changed to init

```
    AFRAME.registerComponent('positionnew', {
  schema: { type: 'vec3', default: {x: 0, y: 2, z: -2} },

   init: function () {
    var object3D = this.el.object3D;
    var data = this.data;
    object3D.position.set(data.x, data.y, data.z);
  }
});
```

Comment: FYI, it should also work on update. I recommend always sharing code people can run and debug. It will help people to help you. Glitch is a great option https://glitch.com/~aframe